# Jquery UI spinner, obtaining the value

Tags: jquery

I created my own widget of the Jquery Ui spinner which shows the data from an array in the spinner it self, so that the user can spin on the values of the spinner and when he chooses a certain value and click on a button then i can retrieve the chosen value inside the spinner... here is the code i used, it is working fine but i don't know where i can implement the part of getting the value of the spinner.

this is the HTML part

`<input id="spinner" onclick="spinner_but();" >`

the java script part:

```
var arrPaperTypes = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]; // this array is supposed to come from the database

$.widget("ui.formatSpinner", $.ui.spinner, {
    options: {
    },
    _parse: function (value) {
        if (typeof value === "string") {                
            return this.options.values.indexOf(value);
        }
        return value;            
    },
    _format: function (value){
        //wrap around
        if (value < 0) {
            value = this.options.values.length-1;
        }
        if (value > this.options.values.length-1) {
            value = 0;
        }
        var format = this.options.values[value];
        return format;
    },  
    change: function(event,ui){
    return $(this).attr("value",$(this).val());
    }   
}); 

$(function() {
    $("#spinner").formatSpinner({
        values: arrPaperTypes
    });
}); 



 // to do implementation of getting the value of the spinner here
  // function spinner_but() {
  }
```

Thanks alot

Comment: could you mind creating a fiddle?

Comment: no actually, but i tried adding the following line in the implementation:

var spinner_but = $("#spinner").formatSpinner("value"); 

but i get an error, it is supposed to fetch the current value of the spinner and save it in the spinner_but variable

Comment: No I said can you create a demo fiddle in **[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)**

Comment: find it please here
http://jsfiddle.net/h5ecx1ux/

Comment: checking on it.. Give me some moment..

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, i am waiting you :)

Comment: I was just checking on it and I feel **[it works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/h5ecx1ux/2/)**. could you please let me know how could I replicate the problem?

Comment: My problem, I need to get the current index of the element inside the spinner so that I can know what the user had chosen.

Comment: and when or on what action you want to get it?